# How to send a mail to a user with views rules when a date is passed?

Tags: views, rules, emails, cron

I have created a date field for all users (in Drupal 7). This date is the end of the user's subscription. When the date of this field is passed, I want to send a mail to the user to tell him he can subscribe again (to access our website).

So, I have created a view with a display rules (with module views rules). I have listed all users who have the field date not empty and filter to have only date passed. I have 2 fields in this view (user name and date). I have edited field info and enable my 2 fields (Data type : user and data type : date) :

[image]

After, I have created a rule wich react on the event "Cron maintenance tasks are performed" and created a view loop on the display rules of my view. In the loop i have added 2 actions : change the date value to exit the user from the view, and send a mail to this user :

[image]

When I Launch the cron, nothing happen. The date is not changed, and the mail is not send. I don't know what configuration I have forgot. Do you have an idea please ?

Thank you for help me.

My rule in export format:

```
{ "rules_relance_e_mail" : {
"LABEL" : "Relance e-mail",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
"ON" : { "cron" : [] },
"DO" : [
  { "VIEW LOOP" : {
      "VIEW" : "dates_de_relances",
      "DISPLAY" : "views_rules_1",
      "ROW VARIABLES" : {
        "name" : { "name" : "Nom" },
        "field_date_de_relance" : { "field_date_de_relance" : "Date de relance" }
      },
      "DO" : [
        { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "field-date-de-relance" ], "value" : "+1 year" } },
        { "mail" : {
            "to" : [ "name:mail" ],
            "subject" : "Test relance",
            "message" : "Test mail",
            "language" : [ "name:language" ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Comment: Please include an export of your Rule (created using the Rules UI), to provide "all" the details of your current rule (the screenprint doesn't show everything to pinpoint the reason why nothing seems to happen ...).

Comment: Thank you Pierre for your answer. I have added my rule export to the post. (It is simple, I have probably forgotten parameters) :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Part 1: Sending an eMail

Your view needs refinement ...You seem to have 1 Views result (row) for each user to be eMailed, which is OK. But that view must have fields (columns) for each of the fields that you want to use in your Rules Action to create your eMail. So the `[name:mail]` and `[name:language]` in your Rules Action should be replaced by some column in your view to make those available. For that you might have to also add a "relationship" in your view to the "user object" (so that eg the eMail ID becomes available).

Have a look at these answers for some more details:

- [How to make fields available in Rules using the Views Rules module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/180542/how-to-make-fields-available-in-rules-using-the-views-rules-module/227633#227633)
- [How to use Rules to send an E-mail after saving a new comment, to users who checked a boolean in their profile?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/214477/how-to-use-rules-to-send-an-e-mail-after-saving-a-new-comment-to-users-who-chec/214511#214511)

#### Part 2: Saving the changed date

You may have to add an extra Rules Action to "save an entity", because you need to remind the Rules module to also save the date you've updated.

Comment: Ok Thank you very much. There is progress.

I add the field user email as a column in my view and configure rules to send e-mail to this field. It works (finally no need relationship in my view) and the mail is sent.

But the change of the value of my date doesn't work. I saw it may have problem with the action "set a data value" and a field date. I search now how to change this date, wich is well present in a column of my view.

Comment: @DavidCKW check the part 2 that I added ... Let me know if that helps to complete your "puzzle" ...

Comment: Could you tell me how add an extra rules action to "save entity" please ? If I add action "save entity" in the views loop, I have only "site:" in the data selector (and not my fields). What is the procedure to do what you advise to me ?

Comment: @DavidCKW I think you should have split this question in 2 separate questions, but maybe this extra tip will help to get it all to work: also pass the "uid" of the user being processed (by adding an extra column for uid in your view). Then add, as the first action inside the views loop a "Fetch entity by id" (to make the user related data availabe). If this tip doesn't help, please consider splitting that part of your question to a new question (as a followup question), and hopefully mark this answer as "accepted" then also. OK?

Comment: thanks. I always have problems for update the user field date, but a mail is sent. I have vote for your answer.

Comment: Finally, all works : In my view, I add a field uid and I parameter It as a data type "User" in the view rules settings. After, in my rule view loop, to set a data value, I use the data selector uid: and so I have acces to all fields of the user And I can change value of all fields. Great thanks to @Pierre.Vriens